Nvidia nemo Neural Diarizer compare speaker embeddings to known speaker embedding
I am trying to label a speaker from a transcribed and diarized conversation using NVIDIA's Nemo NeuralDiarizer to a known speaker embedding. As I understand you can retrieve the cluster embeddings like so:
msdd_model.clustering_embedding.prepare_cluster_embs_infer()
msdd_model.clustering_embedding.emb_sess_test_dict

However this provides a dictionary that doesn't match the allocated number of speakers in the final transcription. Am I looking in the right place?
How can I get the average speaker embeddings that were used to ascertain if a speaker was 0 or 1 or 2 etc?
The goal is I want to compare these with a known speaker embedding and relabel the transcription of a "speaker_00" to this known speaker's name for instance.
